# Getting folder structures in Swift Playground's Resources folder

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I would like to get the subfolders structure in the Resources folder of a Swift Playground.

[image: Folder Structure]

I've tried using this approach with no luck

```
let docsPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + "/Resources"
let directoryContents = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: docsPath)
```

This results in `nil` and I can't get the tree structure of the folders, is this possible?

Comment: As I said in your deleted answer `Bundle.main.resourcePath!` points to the Resources folder of the Xcode application. There is no extra subfolder `Resources`. `urls(forResourcesWithExtension: nil, subdirectory: nil)` lists all resources of Xcode and the current Playground.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

```
let docsPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
let urls = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: nil, subdirectory: "dataset/train")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to allow `NSBundle` to find your resources exactly where they are, so instead of

```
let docsPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + "/Resources"
```

you can use somewhere inside your class (moreover, such class will be transferable to real project)

```
let docsPath = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "dataset", ofType: nil)
```

and you get exact path.

Btw, it can be something like

> /var/folders/gs/hkhcv3rx5wd5lqrfvh1ll6g40000gn/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/resources/620432D5-9F12-4FC8-B271-17153FC9D797/dataset

that is why it's better to avoid hardcoding.